# If I have a unitary matrix, how can I find an orthogonal matrix from it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I am working on a problem where I am just given the characteristic polynomial of some 3x3 matrix $C$ and am asked to show that it is similar to an orthogonal matrix.

So I solved for the roots of the polynomial and found 3 distinct eigenvalues:  1 real, 2 complex.

So $C$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$, with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

I computed $DD^*$, which happened to equal $D^*D$, which equaled to $I$.  So, I know that $C$ is similar to a *unitary* matrix $D$.

However the problem statement asks to show the similarity to an orthogonal matrix, so I wonder whether the matrix $D$ suffices, or whether I have to now find another matrix, from knowing $D$.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your matrix has real entries, in which case your two nonreal eigenvalues are complex conjugates, call them $a\pm bi$. Then $$\pmatrix{a&-b\\ b&a\\}$$ is the orthogonal matrix similar to the unitary matrix with $a\pm bi$ on the diagonal.

Comment: Hi @GerryMyerson, thanks so much.  I verified the computations.  Is there a simple / deeper reason for why the matrix above works?  It's easy to commit this matrix to memory, but I was just curious.  Thanks,

Comment: Multiplication by $i$ is rotation through a right angle, counterclockwise; this is a linear transformation, represented by the matrix $$\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0\\}$$ so we may call that matrix, $i$. Then the orthogonal matrix I gave is $a+bi$ (where I treat the identity matrix as 1).

Comment: Ah, ok.  Can I ask one final question?  So the first matrix you gave, can I treat it as a $2x2$ sub-matrix, and enlarge it to $3x3$, with the last column containing the real eigenvalue at the bottom right corner.  I am guessing that this is the desired $3x3$ orthogonal matrix.  So, is it true?  That the eigenvalues for any sub-matrix will also be the eigenvalues for the full matrix?  Is it a theorem?  Thanks, @GerryMyerson,

Comment: Yes. So long as the matrix is what's called "block diagonal", that works.